# Finding a good inverse for an ill-conditioned matrix transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a time-series observation dataset that has been distorted. I want to recover the best approximation of the original signal as possible. Disclaimer:: I know only the basics of linear algebra, so please bear with me.

I have a good model of the distortion, represented by a square matrix. In theory, if I can find an inverse of the transformation, I can recover the original signal. However, the model of the distortion as a matrix is ill-conditioned (i.e. almost singular).

Is it possible to take this matrix model, and generate an invertible matrix that is an approximation of the original matrix?

Comment: The most robust way I know of is the SVD.

Answer (score 1):

The usual way to approach inverting a matrix that is rank deficient is to use a [**generalized inverse**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_inverse).

This means if your matrix equation is:
$$
y = \mathbf{A}x
$$
where $\mathbf{A}$ is an $n \times m$ matrix, then you can use, for example, the Moore-Penrose pseudo-inverse, $\mathbf{A}^{+}$:
$$
\mathbf{A}^{+} = (\mathbf{A}^*\mathbf{A})^{-1} \mathbf{A}^*
$$
if a *left inverse* is required or
$$
\mathbf{A}^{+} = \mathbf{A}^*(\mathbf{A}\mathbf{A}^*)^{-1}
$$
for the *right inverse*.

If $n=m$ then either be used.

However, as per the link above, there are many different possibilities for selecting an inverse in the rank-deficient / non-square case because the system of equations is [underdetermined](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Underdetermined_system).

As per @MBaz's comment, you can calculate this [using the singular value decomposition of $\mathbf{A}$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/19954/5965)

Comment: Yes, I calculated the Moore-Penrose pseudo-inverse with Mathematica. However, the results were unsatisfactory, i.e. the pseudo inverse was not very good at recovering the original signal.

Answer (score 0):

##### Simple Answer

A simple way to solve this is by using diagonal loading (see [this answer](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/300/55647) for a related example). If your square matrix is $R$, then instead of inverting $R$, invert $R + \sigma I$, where $\sigma$ is a small value.

##### Why This Helps

An ill-conditioned matrix (as you probably know) has some near-zero eigenvalues. The condition number of the matrix is the ratio of its largest and smallest eigenvalues, so you can see why you would run into problems with near-zero eigenvalues. Diagonal loading increases all the eigenvalues slightly, moving the smallest ones away from zero and improving the condition number of the matrix.

Comment: The problem with this method is that it introduces a basis-dependent bias which is hard to reason about. I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: It's not perfect, but if computation time is part of the equation, it is less demanding than SVD, for example. It is therefore used in some practical cases.